# Swift - Variables in different files

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, swift, import

I am developing a game in Xcode with Swift.

In my 'SPSwipes.swift' file, a variable is given an initial value. However I have looked all around the internet to find out how to modify that variable in my GameViewController, but I can't find anything. Apparently there is no need to 'import', so how do I access that variable in a different file?

Thanks, Will

Comment: You need to show some code, but it is likely that the variable spies a property in a class called SPSwipes. You need a reference to an instance of that class and then you can use . Notation - myinstance.theProperty

Answer (score 2):

First you have to be sure that the variable has **not** been declared as `private`.

If the file where the variable is declared **and** the file where you are trying to use the variable are in the same module, then there's nothing special to do - just reference the variable from the other file, and it has to work.

If the variable and the source where you want to use it are in different modules, then the variable must be declared as `public` *and* you have to import the module in the file where you want to access it.

I presume your case is the first. If still doesn't work, it would be good to know how you have defined the variable and how you are trying to access to it (which means, share some code).

Comment: It's all the 'referencing' and 'declaring as public' that I am confused about. Please could you edit your answer to include some code? Thanks

Comment: Actually you should modify your question to include some code - then we can provide help and suggestions basing on what you have done

Comment: I haven't done anything because I don't know what to do.

Comment: well it's all about declaring a variable and using it. If you don't know how to do it, then I suggest a course or a book to let you get started with programming - you won't probably find any for swift, but I think there are many beginners-level for objective C (which is still good to know if you want to develop in swift)

Comment: In the short term, please tell me how to 'reference the variable from the other file'. Thanks

Comment: the same as you would do with all local variables in functions, `var x = 0` to define a variable `x`, `x = x * 2` to change it, `print(x)` to read its value etc.

Comment: I declared it in a different file to the one that my if statement is in. My if statement says that it is an 'unresolved identifier'.

Comment: I did the same, define the variable in a file and use it from a method in a view controller and it works - try creating a new project and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

in one file called otherFile.swift , I have

```
class otherFile: NSObject {

    var str:NSString = "hi"
}
```

and in the next file I have

```
println(otherFile().str)
```

this works, make sure you instantiate the object first

Answer (score 0):

In one file, declare a variable like normal:

```
var str = "Value2"
```

In the other file, access the variable like any other:

```
print(str)
str = "Value2"
```

Swift variables are global.